# What happened to the unique users count?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When visiting https://stackapps.com/apps, I used to be able to see how many unique users were using my application - but now all I see is zeroes for all of the apps.

Were the numbers reset or is this feature not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This field will be hidden with the next deploy.

The number had become very unreliable, and of low interest over all (as exemplified by how long it took anyone to notice it was missing...).

I intend to do some more work around app usage statistics as part of 2.0 later this year, 1.x really did not excel in this regard.

Comment: More statistics would be awesome. Thanks for letting us know what's up.